# Initializing static default_random_engine

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a simple class which will be useful for me with generating random numbers using `default_random_engine`.

Random.h:

```
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class Random
{
    public:
        Random();
        ~Random() {}
    private:
        static default_random_engine _engine;
};
```

Random.cpp:

```
#include "Random.h"

Random::Random()
{
    _engine = default_random_engine{}; //Will this be initialized every time I create an object of type Random?
}
```

Will `_engine` be initialized every time I create an object of type `Random`?
I just want it to stay like it is after the first initialization because I was told I can use the same engine multiple times.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, you helped me understand.

Comment: If that `using namespace std;` is there for reasons other than making the code in this very question shorter: Please don't. Putting it in a `.cpp` is already bad enough, but in headers, it's rather unacceptable.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link @NathanOliver provided in my question helped me understand, which is to make a global variable of that type in the source file:

```
#include "random.h"

default_random_engine Question::_engine = default_random_engine{};

Random::Random() {  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Will _engine be initialized every time I create an object of type Random?

Yes.

> I just want it to stay like it is after the first initialization

In which case, you should define it like so:

```
#include "Random.h"

std::default_random_engine Random::_engine;
```

Without this, even your original version won't compile (as you've not defined the static member).

Comment: He needs to define it like that regardless. In order to get his desired result, he simply needs to not reassign it in his constructor (or anywhere else).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley true, I'll add this to my answer, thanks! :)